# Can I have different dynamics for different tools? (GIMP)

Tags: gimp, drawing

I've just started to use GIMP as I can't afford to get Photoshop and I've been trying to set it up for a bit of drawing (which is a huge pain) and I've run into a problem with the eraser. I've got a dynamic which allows for GIMP to sense my Wacoms pressure which is wonderful with the brush but I don't want this affect to be used with the eraser.

Personally I want my eraser to completely erase what I select rather than dim it so I was wondering if anyone knew a way to make the brush and eraser tools use different dynamics.

Answer (score 2):

`Edit>Preferences->Tool options->Paint options shared between tools` and un-tick `Dynamics`.